# page reloads when updating redux state/submitting form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to set up a simple react-redux flow where an input updates state and a form submits the value in the component's state to a redux action function. However, whenever the form submits, the page reloads and when I add `e.preventDefault()` to the submit function, I get

> TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

I've tried adding `e.preventDefault()` to the submitToRedux function but when I add do, I get `TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`

Here is my Child1.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { changeName } from "../redux/name/name.actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function Child1(state) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const changeHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitToRedux = e => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    changeName(name);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>CHILD ONE</h2>
      <form onSubmit={submitToRedux(name)}>
        <input type="text" onChange={changeHandler} />
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        <h2>name in Child1 state: {name}</h2>
        <h2>name in redux: {state.name.name}</h2>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  name: state.name
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Child1);
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";

import Child1 from "./components/Child1";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child1 />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

root-reducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import nameReducer from "./name/nameReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  name: nameReducer
});
```

and nameReducer.js:

```
import NameActionTypes from "./name.types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  name: "Mike"
};

const nameReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NameActionTypes.CHANGE_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default nameReducer;
```

I expect it to update the `state.name.name` value in Child1.js to whatever is submitted from the state in the Child1.js component when the form is submitted but instead it just reloads the page and since I'm not persisting it to local storage it just remains blank. When I add `e.preventDefault()` I expect it to stop reloading the page when the form submits but it then says that

> e.preventDefault is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not passing the submit event to submitToRedux function.
You should pass it to your function like this:

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => submitToRedux(e, name)}>
```

and then you handle it in you function like this:

```
const submitToRedux = (e, name) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeName(name);
  };
```

Here is how child1.js will be:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { changeName } from "../redux/name/name.actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function Child1(state) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const changeHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitToRedux = (e, name) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeName(name);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>CHILD ONE</h2>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => submitToRedux(e, name)}>
        <input type="text" onChange={changeHandler} />
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        <h2>name in Child1 state: {name}</h2>
        <h2>name in redux: {state.name.name}</h2>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  name: state.name
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Child1);
```

Comment: this worked, plus i forgot to add dispatch() to my submitToRedux function like so ```const submitToRedux = (e, name) => {
    console.log("name: ", name);
    e.preventDefault();
    props.dispatch(changeName(name));
    console.log("from submittoredux function", props.name.name);
  };```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issue's with your code,

First, you are writing `state` as argument to `Child1` component

```
function Child1(state) {
```

which should be,

```
function Child1(props) {
```

You should set this `props` to your `state`,

```
const [name, setName] = useState(props.name);
```

Your `input` should be controlled,

```
<input type="text" onChange={changeHandler} value={name} />
```

You should print `name` like this,

```
<h2>name in Child1 state: {name}</h2>
<h2>name in redux: {props.name}</h2>
```

Your form submit method should be like this,

```
<form onSubmit={submitToRedux}>
```

And finally your `submitToRedux` function,

```
const submitToRedux = e => {
    e.preventDefault();  //Now this will work
    changeName(name); //As we have controlled input, we direclty take name from state
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the function that will get called once the form is submitted.

```
<form onSubmit={submitToRedux}>
```

But instead you are actually calling it right away:

```
<form onSubmit={submitToRedux(name)}>
```

When you just pass the function, the form will take care of calling it with a submit event as parameter.
In your code the error says the parameter `e` should contain a function `preventDefault`, which clearly is not defined in the variable you are passing in as parameter when you do: `submitToRedux(name)`